# Cannot drop a draggable where two droppables touch each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

It seems that when using two jquery UI droppables that touch each other, the droppable events are not fired correctly.  If, while dragging a draggable from over one of the elements to *just* below it onto the next element, then the out event is fired for the first droppable, but the over event is not fired for the second.  If you drop at this point, no drop event is fired.

An example is best.  Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwLhD/5/) (tested in IE7,8,9 and Chrome11).  Make sure your browser's console log is open.  If you drag the draggable over the first row, then slowly drag towards the second row, you'll soon see in the log that the out event for the first row is fired, but the over event for the second row is not.  If you drop when this happens, the drop event is not fired.

It seems to just be a 1 pixel line in between the rows that causes the problem.  Dragging one more pixel causes the over event to be fired, and the drop event to work correctly.

This looks like a bug to me, but I can't find anyone else who has used table rows as droppables and has reported the problem.  I styled the table so you can see that the rows are indeed flush together with no space in between.

This is a big problem for me because in our app, the table rows are nested greedy droppables.  So if the user drops when this happens, the drop is actually picked up by the outer droppable instead.

Also, we give feedback to the user in the draggable helper in the form of an icon and message that changes depending on the droppable you are over.  When you drag between rows, it flickers for a moment, as it thinks you are not over any droppable when you actually are.

My questions:

1. Is there any fix or workaround for this issue?
2. Should I report this as a bug?

### Update

@davin,

We did end up changing the drag function in $.ui.ddmanager to fix the event ordering.  Our issue was we have nested greedy droppables.  When you moved from one of these nested droppables to the other from bottom to top, the over event would actually fire for the parent last, causing bad things to happen.

So we added logic to basically check if moving from one nested greedy to another, and if so, not fire parent events.

Would it be too much to ask to have you look this over real quick and make sure our logic makes sense?  There are two logical changes.  If we moved from greedy child to greedy child:

1. Don't unset parentInstance.greedyChild
2. Don't fire parentInstance._over event.

Here's the code.  See the lines dealing with the isParentStateChanged closure var, which we added:

```
    drag: function(draggable, event) {

    //If you have a highly dynamic page, you might try this option. It renders positions every time you move the mouse.
    if(draggable.options.refreshPositions) $.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets(draggable, event);

    var isParentStateChanged = false;

    //Run through all droppables and check their positions based on specific tolerance options
    $.each($.ui.ddmanager.droppables[draggable.options.scope] || [], function() {

        if(this.options.disabled || this.greedyChild || !this.visible) return;
        var intersects = $.ui.intersect(draggable, this, this.options.tolerance);

        var c = !intersects && this.isover == 1 ? 'isout' : (intersects && this.isover == 0 ? 'isover' : null);
        if(!c) return;

        var parentInstance;
        if (this.options.greedy && !isParentStateChanged) {
            var parent = this.element.parents(':data(droppable):eq(0)');
            if (parent.length) {
                parentInstance = $.data(parent[0], 'droppable');
                parentInstance.greedyChild = (c == 'isover' ? 1 : 0);
            }
        }

        // we just moved into a greedy child
        if (parentInstance && c == 'isover') {
            isParentStateChanged = true;

            parentInstance['isover'] = 0;
            parentInstance['isout'] = 1;
            parentInstance._out.call(parentInstance, event);
        }

        this[c] = 1; this[c == 'isout' ? 'isover' : 'isout'] = 0;
        this[c == "isover" ? "_over" : "_out"].call(this, event);

        // we just moved out of a greedy child
        if (parentInstance && c == 'isout') {

            if (!isParentStateChanged) {
                parentInstance['isout'] = 0;
                parentInstance['isover'] = 1;
                parentInstance._over.call(parentInstance, event);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, I modified your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/squidbe/vwLhD/7/) to use divs and got the same result, so it doesn't appear to matter that you're using a table. Perhaps this behavior is intended.

Comment: @squidbe, thanks for that good info.  Edited title and initial description to be more generic given that it happens not just with table rows.

Comment: check out my plugin.. myabe it will help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16720944/1308461][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16720944/1308461

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug per se, it's a feature. It's all a matter of definitions. You've defined the tolerance of your droppable items to be pointer, which according to the docs is:

> **pointer**: mouse pointer overlaps the droppable

When my mouse pointer is at (10,10) and the top left corner of my box ends at (10,10), is that overlapping? It depends on your definition. jQueryUI's definition is strong inequality, or strong overlap ([see the relevant code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.core.js#L299)). That makes sense (to me), since I'm not inside the box if I'm only on the edge, so I wouldn't want an event to fire.

Although if for your purposes you require weak inequality in the overlap condition (i.e. weak overlap), you can modify that line of code in your source, or override it, by adding:

```
$.ui.isOverAxis = function( x, reference, size ) {
    return ( x >= reference ) && ( x <= ( reference + size ) );
};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vwLhD/8/

Be aware that with weak inequality comes other bumps in the road: your `out` event will fire after your `over` event, so you might have two over events before a single `out` has fired. That's not so hard to handle, but you need to make sure you deal with that case.

**UPDATE:**

It's important to note that if you add the code I pasted above it is going to affect all other ui widgets in the scope of `$` if that's important. Maybe subbing `$` could avoid that.

In any case, I have a second workaround that will solve the above issue entirely, and now on every mouse movement the pointer is either in or out of every element exclusively:

```
$.ui.isOverAxis2 = function( x, reference, size ) {
    return ( x >= reference ) && ( x < ( reference + size ) );
};
$.ui.isOver = function( y, x, top, left, height, width ) {
    return $.ui.isOverAxis2( y, top, height ) && $.ui.isOverAxis( x, left, width );
};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vwLhD/10/

Essentially I've made the upper condition a weak inequality and the lower one a strong one. So the borders are entirely adjacent. Now the events fire almost perfectly. Almost and not entirely because the plugin still loops through the droppables in order, so if I'm dragging from top to bottom the firing order is good because first it detects that I have left the higher element, and then detects that I have entered the lower element, whereas dragging from bottom to top the order of firing is reversed - first it fires entering the higher and only then leaving the lower.

The difference between this and the previous workaround is that even though half the time the order is not good, it all happens in one tick, i.e. over-out or out-over are always together, the user can never get stuck as in the original case and first workaround.

You can further hone this to be **absolutely** perfect by changing the ui code to loop through the items first according to those that have the mouse over them, and only then the rest (in the `$.ui.ddmanager` function). That way the mouse leave will always fire first. Alternatively you can swap the order and have the reverse order; whatever suits you better.

That certainly would solve your problem entirely.

Comment: @mazlix, it worked for me in chrome. Care to explain *why* exactly you think it doesn't work? "Doesn't work" helps everyone about as much as a sore tooth.

Comment: sorry, i meant that if i drag the item and move my cursor slowly from row2 to row1 my console.log fires over1 twice then i have to move another pixel and it fires over2. Ideally I would imagine it fires over1 and out1 in the same event, but now I realize for the OP that probbably doesn't matter, as he could just go off the second over1 event. You done good!

Comment: @mazlix, I mentioned that in my post. In any case I have a workaround that should solve even that little nuisance. I'll update the post

Comment: @davin, thanks for the detailed workarounds and explanation.  I will try in the morning.  I see the events firing oddly, as you noted, when going bottom to top, and this is, in fact, important to me.  However, I already have a solution for ignoring stale out events since I ran into this in other cases as well.  So I may not (hopefully!) have to override more than you've given.

Comment: as a side note, I find it odd that the droppable doesn't work the way you mentioned by default, checking for having to fire out events before new over events.

Comment: also just for the sake of argument and for fun, I cannot agree that the default definition of "overlap" makes sense.  You said "I'm not inside the box if I'm only on the edge".  But you're defining "edge" differently for the top than for the bottom.  The second inequality (the lower bound) is also an edge.  By the given logic, I would expect the determination to be x > reference && x < (reference + size - 1).  In all of the world of graphics, coordinates of an object in a standard x-y are defined by (x, y, x+sx-1, y+sy-1).  Discrete "overlap" then means any of those coords or the interior.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be dropping **between** rows which would mean you were dropping onto the table. Do you have your table borders collapsed? css `border-collapse: collapsed;`

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do have borders collapsed in our application, but as you can see in the fiddle, the same behavior happens without collapsed borders and in fact without any borders at all.  I also tested this in the application with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a project i was working on.

My solution was to see check how far the draggable was over each droppable. If the draggable is 50% over the top droppable then i assume the user wants to drop on the top droppable.

Similar for the bottom.

To do this i changed $.ui.intersect;

added vars - 
    hw = droppable.proportions.width / 2, hh = droppable.proportions.height / 2,
    lhw = l + hw,
    thh = t + hh

then add some if statements

```
// going down
if(y2 < b && y2 >= thh){}

// going up
if(y1 > t && y1 <= thh){}

// covered
if(y1 <= t && y2 >= b){}
```