# dropping an element only into the droppable that is in front

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, droppable

I have some droppable areas, which are also draggable. It can happen that two or more droppable areas will get behind each other. Is there a way to drop a draggable item only into the area that is in the front? (z-index)

The situation is now, that the item gets added to all the areas, that are overlapping.

Thank you

Comment: I have tried to set the accept option of the droppable to null and then set it later, when a moveover/hover event triggers. but it still triggers all the droppables.

Comment: Could you make a short jsfiddle showing the problem?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997053/jqueryui-droppable-stop-propagation-to-overlapped-sibling

Comment: yeah this is a nice solution, but I still need to determine which area is on the top front. The linked solution works only with another static non-moving droppable Area. I tried to save the area ids, that are triggered by the droppable action; than look which one has the highest z-index, and revert the last actions from the rest. But this is very hacky and brings many other small limitations/bugs. Maybe I will try it with a collision detection, to know which elements I have to disable with your linked solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have now a quite good solution and I want to share it with you guys...
I have build a small plugin

https://github.com/vaceta/jquery-top-droppable

Comment: it would have been great if you could explain wid a fiddle